# Java 8 java.util.stream.Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I see many blog posts mention a Streams class and I see it was once [part of the lambda branch API](http://download.java.net/lambda/b78/docs/api/java/util/stream/Streams.html). It appears to be non-public API now and it [does not match the previous implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b91/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Streams.java). Is there a different way to do `Streams.concat()` or to append multiple values to a stream?

Comment: You should mention what pre-release build(s) you are referencing.

Comment: @assylias I'll accept that as an answer until it does get implemented, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Streams` class got split and some of its methods were moved to [StreamSupport](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html), which does not contain a `concat` method in the latest build. The rationale for the split is explained [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-April/001649.html).

The specific case of `concat` has been mentioned separately in [this post](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-May/001718.html) where it was proposed for removal and was apparently removed.

However [a later post](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-May/001806.html) seems to indicate that it will reappear in future builds.