# Does Java 8 provide a good way to repeat a value or function?

Tags: java, java-8

In many other languages, eg. Haskell, it is easy to repeat a value or function multiple times, eg. to get a list of 8 copies of the value 1:

```
take 8 (repeat 1)
```

but I haven't found this yet in Java 8.  Is there such a function in Java 8's JDK?

Or alternatively something equivalent to a range like

```
[1..8]
```

It would seem an obvious replacement for a verbose statement in Java like

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

to have something like

```
Range.from(1, 8).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i))
```

though this particular example doesn't look much more concise actually...  but hopefully it's more readable.

Comment: Have you studied the [Streams API](http://download.java.net/lambda/b78/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)? That should be your best bet as far as the JDK is concerned. It's got a [range](http://download.java.net/lambda/b78/docs/api/java/util/stream/Streams.html#intRange%28int%2C+int%29) function, that's what I have found so far.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The Streams class [has been removed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780647/java-8-java-util-stream-streams) (more precisely it has been split among several other classes and some methods have been completely removed).

Comment: I defer to the authority here, as far as Java 8 I'm still just a casual onlooker.

Comment: You call a for loop verbose! It's a good thing you weren't around in the Cobol days.  It took over 10 declarative statements in Cobol to display ascending numbers.  Young people these days don't appreciate how good they have it.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc How do you know how old I am? :)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc verbosity has nothing to do with it. Loops are not composable, Streams are. Loops lead to unavoidable repetition, while Streams permit reuse. As such Streams are a quantitatively better abstraction than loops and should be preferred.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc and we had to code in bare feet, in the snow.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

For this specific example, you could do:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 8)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you need a step different from 1, you can use a mapping function, for example, for a step of 2:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 8)
         .map(i -> 2 * i - 1)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or build a custom iteration and limit the size of the iteration:

```
IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 2)
         .limit(8)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Ah, so you are already on first name terms with Streams, good to know :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes - could not resist!

Comment: Closures will completely transform Java code, for the better. Looking forward to that day...

Comment: closures will be a disaster, and the death of Java as they make it utterly unreadable.

Comment: @jwenting It really depends - typically with GUI stuff (Swing or JavaFX), that removes *a lot* of boiler plate due to anonymous classes.

Comment: @jwenting To anyone with experience in FP, code which revolves around higher-order functions is a pure win. To anyone without that experience, it's time to upgrade your skills---or risk being left behind in the dust.

Comment: assylias, so what you're saying with your latest edit, they've removed [this one](http://download.java.net/lambda/b78/docs/api/java/util/stream/Streams.html#intRange%28int,%20int,%20int%29)?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You might want to use a slightly newer version of the javadoc (you are pointing to build 78, latest is build 105: http://download.java.net/lambda/b105/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html )

Comment: Nice! Additionally you should be able to use a method reference in the `forEach` rather than the lambda, e.g.: `.forEach(System.out::println)`.

Comment: @assylias Cool, very glad to see we have a range in Java 8.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there also a way to simply call a method that takes no arguments N times?

Comment: @GraemeMoss You could still use the same pattern (`IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 8).forEach(i -> methodNoArgs());`) but it confuses thing IMO and in that case a loop seems indicated.

Comment: @assylias But what if you want to generate, say, 8 strings and then do something with them?  msandiford's answer seems nearest.  I think then I would do Stream.generate(this::createString).limit(8).  Cool. :)

Comment: @GraemeMoss The new APIs are quite extensive and there are often many ways to do the same thing, which are more or less appropriate and straightforward depending on the exact use case.

Comment: I would prefer `IntStream.range(start, end)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int- over `rangeClosed`. Here's an example. https://metamug.com/blog/write-a-java-program-to-print-christmas-tree

Answer (score 80):

Here's another technique I ran across the other day:

```
Collections.nCopies(8, 1)
           .stream()
           .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

The `Collections.nCopies` call creates a `List` containing `n` copies of whatever value you provide. In this case it's the boxed `Integer` value 1. Of course it doesn't actually create a list with `n` elements; it creates a "virtualized" list that contains only the value and the length, and any call to `get` within range just returns the value. The `nCopies` method has been around since the Collections Framework was introduced way back in JDK 1.2. Of course, the ability to create a stream from its result was added in Java SE 8.

Big deal, another way to do the same thing in about the same number of lines.

However, this technique is faster than the `IntStream.generate` and `IntStream.iterate` approaches, and surprisingly, it's also faster than the `IntStream.range` approach.

For `iterate` and `generate` the result is perhaps not too surprising. The streams framework (really, the Spliterators for these streams) is built on the assumption that the lambdas will potentially generate different values each time, and that they will generate an unbounded number of results. This makes parallel splitting particularly difficult. The `iterate` method is also problematic for this case because each call requires the result of the previous one. So the streams using `generate` and `iterate` don't do very well for generating repeated constants.

The relatively poor performance of `range` is surprising. This too is virtualized, so the elements don't actually all exist in memory, and the size is known up front. This should make for a fast and easily parallelizable spliterator. But it surprisingly didn't do very well. Perhaps the reason is that `range` has to compute a value for each element of the range and then call a function on it. But this function just ignores its input and returns a constant, so I'm surprised this isn't inlined and killed.

The `Collections.nCopies` technique has to do boxing/unboxing in order to handle the values, since there are no primitive specializations of `List`. Since the value is the **same** every time, it's basically boxed once and that box is shared by all `n` copies. I suspect boxing/unboxing is highly optimized, even intrinsified, and it can be inlined well.

Here's the code:

```
    public static final int LIMIT = 500_000_000;
    public static final long VALUE = 3L;

    public long range() {
        return
            LongStream.range(0, LIMIT)
                .parallel()
                .map(i -> VALUE)
                .map(i -> i % 73 % 13)
                .sum();
}

    public long ncopies() {
        return
            Collections.nCopies(LIMIT, VALUE)
                .parallelStream()
                .mapToLong(i -> i)
                .map(i -> i % 73 % 13)
                .sum();
}
```

And here are the JMH results: (2.8GHz Core2Duo)

```
Benchmark                    Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
c.s.q.SO18532488.ncopies    thrpt         5        7.547        2.904    ops/s
c.s.q.SO18532488.range      thrpt         5        0.317        0.064    ops/s
```

There is a fair amount of variance in the ncopies version, but overall it seems comfortably 20x faster than the range version. (I'd be quite willing to believe that I've done something wrong, though.)

I'm surprised at how well the `nCopies` technique works. Internally it doesn't do very much special, with the stream of the virtualized list simply being implemented using `IntStream.range`! I had expected that it would be necessary to create a specialized spliterator to get this to go fast, but it already seems to be pretty good.

Comment: This actually answers the OP's question.

Comment: Less seasoned developers might be confused or get into trouble when they learn that `nCopies` doesn't actually _copy_ anything and the "copies" all point to that one single object. It's always safe if that object is _immutable_, such as a boxed primitive in this example.  You allude to this in your "boxed once" statement, but it might be nice to explicitly call out the caveats here because that behavior is not specific to auto-boxing.

Comment: So that implies that `LongStream.range` is significantly slower than `IntStream.range`? So it’s a good thing that the idea of not offering an `IntStream` (but use `LongStream` for all integer types) has been dropped. Note that for the sequential use case, there isn’t a reason to use stream at all: `Collections.nCopies(8, 1).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));` does the same as `Collections.nCopies(8, 1).stream().forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));` but even more efficient might be `Collections.<Runnable>nCopies(8, () -> System.out.println(1)).forEach(Runnable::run);`

Comment: @Holger, these tests were performed on clean type profile, so they are unrelated to real world. Probably `LongStream.range` performs worse, because it has two maps with `LongFunction` inside, while `ncopies` has three maps with `IntFunction`, `ToLongFunction` and `LongFunction`, thus all lambdas are monomorphic. Running this test on pre-polluted type profile (which is closer to the real-world case) shows that `ncopies` is 1.5x slower.

Comment: Premature Optimization FTW

Comment: The `.stream()` is not necessary - `List` implements `Iterable` which has a `forEach` method.

Comment: I am skeptical about wether it is really faster than .range since stream() implementation of CopiesList actually calls IntStream.range ?

Comment: For the sake of completeness, it would be nice to see a benchmark that compares both of these techniques with a plain old `for` loop.  While your solution is faster than the `Stream` code, my guess is that a `for` loop would beat either of these by a significant margin.

Answer (score 39):

For completeness, and also because I couldn't help myself :)

Generating a limited sequence of constants is fairly close to what you would see in Haskell, only with Java level verboseness.

```
IntStream.generate(() -> 1)
         .limit(8)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: `() -> 1` would only generate 1's, is this intended? So the output would be `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`.

Comment: Yes, per the OP's first Haskell example `take 8 (repeat 1)`.  assylias pretty much covered all the other cases.

Comment: `Stream<T>` also has a generic `generate` method for getting an infinite stream of some other type, which can be limited the same way.

Answer (score 16):

Once a repeat function is somewhere defined as

```
public static BiConsumer<Integer, Runnable> repeat = (n, f) -> {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        f.run();
};
```

You can use it now and then this way, e.g.:

```
repeat.accept(8, () -> System.out.println("Yes"));
```

To get and equivalent to Haskell's

```
take 8 (repeat 1)
```

You could write

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
repeat.accept(8, () -> s.append("1"));
```

Comment: This one is awesome. However I modified it to provide the number of the iteration back, by changing the `Runnable` to `Function<Integer, ?>` and then using `f.apply(i)`.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use the `Stream.generate()` method. For example the snippet below will create a list with 5 instances of `MyClass`:

```
List<MyClass> timezones = Stream
    .generate(MyClass::createInstance)
    .limit(5)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

From java doc:

> generate(Supplier s)
> Returns an infinite sequential unordered
> stream where each element is generated by the provided Supplier.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution to implementing the times function. I'm a junior so I admit it could be not ideal, I'd be glad to hear if this is not a good idea for whatever reason.

```
public static <T extends Object, R extends Void> R times(int count, Function<T, R> f, T t) {
    while (count > 0) {
        f.apply(t);
        count--;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here's some example usage:

```
Function<String, Void> greet = greeting -> {
    System.out.println(greeting);
    return null;
};

times(3, greet, "Hello World!");
```