# Fortify flagging query as sqlInjection when passing in parameters to a method

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-injection, fortify

We have a method in our database layer which looks like this:

```
public List<String> getNamesFromId(List<Long> idsList){
   StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
   query.append("Select first_name from person where id in (");

    for (int pos = 0; pos < idsList.size(); pos++) {
        query.append("?");
        query.append(",");
    }
    query.deleteCharAt(query.length() - 1).append(")");

    try {
        conn = establishConnection();           
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < selections.size(); i++) {
            pstmt.setLong(i + 1, idsList.get(i));
        }
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //
    }

    try {
       List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (rs.next()) {


                namesList.add(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));


        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //
    }
    // close the Connection object
    try {
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //
    }
```

During our fortify scan it is flagging this as SQL Injection saying 
"invokes a SQL query built using input potentially coming from an untrusted source. This call could allow an attacker to modify the statement's meaning or to execute arbitrary SQL commands."

Is this because this is a public facing method and we are passing in the parameters for the IN part of the prepared statement? If so how can we do it better? Or is it a false alarm from fortify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a false alarm, you're doing it the right way.

There are frameworks that can help you with this (e.g. Spring's `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, but they basically do the same thing under the hood.

The static analyzer is probably catching the fact you're building your query by concatenating strings, or that the size of input is somehow involved, and flagging it as a danger (only guessing here).

---

On a side note, a potential problem that however has nothing to do with SQL injection is that you can only use certain number (DB-dependent) of those parameters - AFAIK the limit's 1000 in Oracle, about 2000 in Teradata, not sure about others. If you need to put many values in that `IN` clause, you'll need to use a different approach like using a temporary table or performing the query in smaller batches and merging the results in Java.

Comment: @user1623627 you can also skip the for loop and the delete workaround by using a **IntSteam.rangeClosed().map()** to generate the **?**'s and **StringJoiner** to put **,**'s between them. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18532568 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html

Comment: @AlainO'Dea good point. Or if on pre-8 Java, you could use [`StringUtils.repeat()` from Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) (it might actually turn out more readable and thus worth considering even in Java 8).

Comment: FWIW pre Java 8 shouldn't be in production anywhere as it no longer gets security patches.  Readability is a bit of a matter of time. If the IntStream idiom becomes common it has the advantage of being in the standard library.