# fortify positive false Sql injection

Tags: java, fortify

I'm using fortify to scan a project I found that I have some positive false for Sql injection. In fact, I have a dynamic query `"select * from " + tabelName`  I created a function to clean the tableName variable as described here http://bigsec.net/b52/Fortify/rules-schema/References/Custom%20Rule%20Examples.htm

But fortify still shows the positive false sql injection in the analysis report.

I'm using java 8 fortify 16

Thanks,

Comment: I would try looking at this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658390/fortify-flagging-query-as-sqlinjection-when-passing-in-parameters-to-a-method

Comment: thanks, @Aaron I had a look at that post yes I agree it's a positive false. but my issue is how to not show this in the report, I mean force fortify to ignore it

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you've reviewed your routine and that it is safe for SQL injection (via quoting and a whitelist of characters for example).  Once done, you need to teach Fortify that this is a validation routine for SQL injection. This will ensure any trace that correctly validates with this routine is not reported.

You should register the whitelist routine as a validation routine by adding a custom rule via the rules editor via a validation / cleansing rule that adds a taint flag of taintFlag="VALIDATED_SQL_INJECTION" - the sink rules for SQL injection should then not report issues with this taint.

For more information on using the taint flags see https://community.softwaregrp.com/dcvta86296/attachments/dcvta86296/fortify-discussions/2950/1/HP_Fortify_SCA_Custom_Rules_Guide_4.21.pdf