# How can I create a method in Java to create a new loop type?

Tags: java, function, loops, for-loop, methods

I'm working on creating some Java methods to make writing code quicker and more efficient, and right now I'm trying to make a simple loop I'm calling "repeat."

It will work something like this:

```
repeat(number of times to repeat) {
   code to be repeated
}
```

So for example:

```
repeat(3) {
   System.out.println("hi")
}
```

Would display:

```
hi
hi
hi
```

**How can I make a method/function like this?** I also need it to work as a nested loop.

Comment: Your method syntax doesn't make sense. Perhaps you meant to have 2 parameters, one for the number of times to repeat, and the other for the code that needs to repeat (perhaps as a Runnable).

Comment: and yes, you *should* use a for-loop. If you can't, you might want to mention in your question why this strange restriction.

Comment: You could try using `IntStream.forEach()`, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532488/does-java-8-provide-a-good-way-to-repeat-a-value-or-function#answer-18532568) for an example. Perhaps this will suit your needs?

Comment: How will adding methods that merely replicate existing features make coding quicker? or more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
repeat(3) {
   System.out.println("hi")
}
```

1. Java does not support this grammar. If you want to support this via the grammar, try another language that supports closures
2. Another way you can try, Java can implement it by lambda

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   repeat(3, () -> {
       System.out.println("hi");
   });
}

public static void repeat(int count, Runnable function) {
   for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      function.run();
   }
}
```

Comment: I think `Runnable` is better than `Consumer`, as there is no value to be consumed.

Comment: yes, runnable is more suitable

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Too bad Java doesn't support the grammar I wanted. Just wondering: does JS support this type of function?

Comment: If you are stick to JVM then you can take a look at Kotlin - it is JVM language and supports this type of grammar to create your own constructions. And it already has its built-in `repeat(N) { ... }` (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to avoid all for loops you could use a recursive version of @math-chen's solution:

```java
public static void repeat(int count, Runnable function) {
        if (count > 0) {
           function.run();
           repeat(count - 1, function);
        }
}
```

As the recursive call is at the end of the method, this "tail-call" can in theory be optimised to not use any extra stack, but the JVM may not do that. (And experiment shows that it doesn't)